# Mouse hover zoom image to be only shown when mouse hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousehover

I have made this mouse hover image zoom page. But I want the output to be shown on the left side and only when someone hovers the mouse on it. In this code the output window is continuously opened.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```js
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);

  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {
      x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    }
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {
      y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      y = 0;
    }
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }
}

// Initiate zoom effect:
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="img_girl.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>

<p>The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning.</p>
<p>The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name "img-zoom-result".</p>
<p>Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a javaScript initiates the zoom effect.</p>
```

The code is working perfectly, but the result should be on the right and it should be only shown when user hovers the mouse on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I've modified your CSS. `display: flex` is what you are after.

I then get your code to hide the `result` element and only show it on `mouseover`. I then have it hide on `mouseout`.

You could tweak the CSS etc to match your style, but here's a snippet of what I've got for you;

```js
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  
  /*initialise and hide lens result*/
  result.style.display = "none";
  /*Reveal and hide on mouseover or out*/
  lens.onmouseover = function(){result.style.display = "block";};
  lens.onmouseout = function(){result.style.display = "none";};
  
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
};

imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px; /*match width of #myimage*/
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/risky-assumptions.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result" style=""></div>
</div>

<p>The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning.</p>
<p>The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name "img-zoom-result".</p>
<p>Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a javaScript initiates the zoom effect.</p>
```

If you want me to, I could work on making the lens result an absolute positioned and aligned so that you don't get the text at the bottom jumping. Unless you know how to do all that - hopefully this is sufficient?

Comment: yes, if you could do that then pls. I would be very thankfull to you. Because that shifts my text downward when mouse hovered.

Comment: Just add; ``position: absolute;left: 300px;`` to ``.img-zoom-result`` - Basically you match ``left`` attribute with the ``width`` of image. I have updated my answer.

Comment: but it is not working with any image of bigger size. Try this on this image https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5103Xi7yQgL._SX679_.jpg

Comment: Are you adjusting your values? This image is ``679px`` so you would have to make appropriate adjustments.

Comment: See here a fiddle I made that uses your new image and contains the image width; https://jsfiddle.net/2b6uwL0p/

Answer (score 1):

by default have its opacity: 0; and on mouseenter make it visible by making opacity: 1;

```js
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);

  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {
      x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    }
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {
      y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      y = 0;
    }
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }
}
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");

function show(x) {
  document.getElementById('myresult').style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

#myresult {
  opacity: 0;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Zoom</h1>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img onmouseenter="show()" id="myimage" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/b6/9e/f8b69e6156999b84137f3f0a23701b75.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>

<p>The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning.</p>
<p>The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name "img-zoom-result".</p>
<p>Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a javaScript initiates the zoom effect.</p>
// Initiate zoom effect:
```